# How to format an external hard drive on Android?

Tags: applications, formatting

How can I format or wipe an external hard drive with no partition on it without third party apps? I tried the [MixApplications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixapplications.ultimateusb&pli=1) app but it's paid, in fact all apps that I tried to wipe this HDD are paid.

So is there another way?

Comment: Isn't it detected in settings > storage?

Comment: Nope.It's an IDE HDD which i connect it via IDE/SATA Converter.It's only showing up in notification panel but from there i cannot format it.Also i don't have a PC.

Comment: So... You have that + a USB-SATA adapter? Or the Android device has SATA ports? Either way there's lot of "moving parts" here and you really need to test the hardware under a more "normal" desktop computer environment. Firstly, the HDD itself can be toast; any PATA HDD is now so old that failure should be the first thing coming to anyone's mind. Then there's the adapter that can be faulty as well and/or being used with an incorrect jumper selection on the HDD (depending on the adapter it may require "master" or "cable select") . Then, if connecting by USB that adapter as well can be faulty

Comment: I have a USB SATA/IDE Adapter.I know but right now i do not have access to a Computer.I wanna sell it but i think it faulty as you said.The Adapter it's not faulty,because i've installed the Paragon app and mount it and i could read files from it,i think maybe ths HDD it's faulty because my Android phone restarts when it try to format it from notification panel(where it says "Tap to fix this USB")